# Timer with Async Task

Tags: android, asynchronous, timer

Set Timer within Async Task for webservice responce. and Show  Alrt box after timer complete.

Please help me how should i do this,

I search for this but do not get any satisfied answer.

Thanks in advance

Some Code of Mine is :

```
  private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean> {
        private long time;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {

                // Callint Web service 


                String final_link = "";
                final_link = Method_All.removeSpace(final_link);
                Log.d("Bhavik", " " + final_link);
                try {

                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI(final_link));
                    Log.d("Parser", "XML Get");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            // If Time Difference is 1 minut Show Alert Box.


            Log.d("TestTask1", "Currenttime = " + (System.currentTimeMillis()));

            Log.d("TestTask2", "time = "+ time);

            Log.d("TestTask3", "difftime = "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private final long DELAY = 500; // in ms
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    //TODO alert dialog code
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, DELAY);
```

I am not too sure whether you where looking for this. Please validate.
If it is not answering your question. Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code...

```
public class MyWebservice extends AsyncTask {


    String wSResponse = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       /*starting an individual thread for checking 
           webservice response after specified time */
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                          synchronized (this) {
                            this.wait(your response time in milliss);
                          }
                        if(wSResponse.equals("")){
                          //display alert box and your logic
                        }       

                    }
         }).start();

        // call web service
        wSResponse = webServiceCall(your parameter);

        return null;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one too if you are using http request

```
URL URLObj = null;
HttpURLConnection ConnObj = null;
URLObj = new URL("Http://Url.to.the/webservice");
ConnObj = (HttpURLConnection) URLObj .openConnection();
ConnObj .setConnectTimeout(5000); 
/* This will set the desired time out for the connection request */
```

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA i apologize